# hasMany relation OctoberCMS | Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, relation, octobercms

i'm trying to build backend for the system which already has it database structure established.
During the development process i've faced an issue with getting hasMany relation to work.

I have 2 database tables:

- permissions
- roles

Problem is that in the roles database, structure looks like this

```
RoleID  |   PermissionID
1   |       1
1   |       2
1   |       3
2   |       3
3   |       5
```

So as you can see, there are actually 3 entries for role 1, which also linked to 3 permissions.

And for permissions table, there are only 2 columns: id and name

So far i've managed to get it working, however, due to the fact that there are many entries for one role (at least i think so), i'm only getting 1 permission per role.

The question is: How can i get all permissions for one role using relations.

Current code for **PermissionModel.php**

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'roles'  =>  [
        'Vendor\Database\Models\RoleModel',
        'table' =>  'roles',
        'key => 'permissionID',
        'otherKey' => 'id'
    ]
];
```

Current code for **RoleModel.php**

```
public $hasMany = [
    'permissions'    =>  [
        'Vendor\Database\Models\PermissionModel',
        'table'     =>  'permissions',
        'key'       =>  'id',
        'otherKey'  =>  'permissionID'
    ]
];
```

And when i'm querying the Role model, i'm just getting 1 permission per role entry, so if there are 20 permissions per role, i'll be getting 20 arrays instead of 1 with 20 values.

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you.

SQL Query which will do the job in that case should look something like this (tested and working just fine)

```
SELECT 
    roles.id as roleID,  
    (SELECT name FROM permissions WHERE permissions.id = 1) as roleName,  
    permissions.id as permissionID,  
    permissions.name as permissionName 
FROM 
    permissions
LEFT JOIN
    roles ON roles.permissionId = permissions.id
WHERE 
    roles.id = 1;
```

Comment: If you want all permission for a single role then your relation could be 1:M that means one role with multiple permission so I would suggest just try by putting belongsTo in PermissionModel instead of belongsToMany

Comment: @AlankarMore Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, i've already tried that approach and i'm still getting 1 permission value in response

Answer (score 3):

`Roles` and `Permissions` have `many-to-many` relationship, one role has many permissions and one permission has many roles. You are using `one-to-many` relationship which is wrong. `$hasMany` is meant to be used for `one-to-many` relationships. You have to use `$belongsToMany` instead, for both models. You need to have three tables:

1. `Permissions` (2 columns: id and name)
2. `Roles` (2 columns: id and name)
3. `Roles_Permissions` (2 columns: RoleID, PermissionID)

Take a look at [many to many relationships](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#many-to-many) and try to fix your approach.

Comment: this is the correct answer, please flag as such